# Insert multiple rows by one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert multiple rows by one mysql query.this is my full code.but it's didn't work.it's display error.

```
$res_name=$_POST['res_name'];
$mail=$_SESSION["email"];

$sql="INSERT INTO opening  
                    (res_id,res_name,email,day,start,end) 

                        VALUES
                        (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','monday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                        (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Tuesday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                        (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Wednesday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                        (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Thursday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                        (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Friday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                        (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Saturday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                        (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Sunday','00:00:00','00:00:00')";

                $result=mysql_query($sql)or die ("Error");
```

Comment: *"it's display error."* - which is? Oh yes that's right `("Error")` that doesn't do anything. Use `or die(mysql_error())`. Plus, hard to say if you've even started the session and that your POST is coming in as it should.

Comment: Here: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, besides what I've given you above for your query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- session and post working fine.error reporting didn't show anything.

Comment: If your form doesn't contain/specify a POST method, then it will fail silently. Form defaults to GET when not specified. This is something I have seen many times before. Also column types and lengths are another factor.

Comment: I think you have forgot to write database connection.

Comment: You are indeed connected using `mysql_` and not another API, right? Your form is correct, POST method, elements named, no typos? Too many possible factors at play. There should be errors being thrown somewhere. This doesn't add up.

Comment: the code is working fine i have tested it with `PDO`,`mysqli` and `mysql`

Comment: i'v realize my error.it's db column data type error.thanks for support.

Comment: Just as I said [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598980/insert-multiple-rows-by-one-mysql-query#comment45504391_28598980) earlier. That should have been made an answer.

Comment: What you should have done instead of accepting an answer that doesn't answer what the real problem was; is to put in an answer of your own. We're building a library containing facts about known issues, not code that somebody tested on their end. What the ***real problem*** was, and as you said "data type error", something that I asked you to check. Therefore, this Q&A will not serve anyone later on should the question be visited. This Q&A is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you connect to your database but there's nothing wrong with your script. I have tested it with `PDO`, `mysqli_query` and `mysql_query` and it's working fine. below is the code I have used to test.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "data";

$con = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or  
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db($dbname);  

$res_name="JHB";
$mail="john@john.com";
$sql="INSERT INTO opening  
                (res_id,res_name,email,day,start,end) 

                    VALUES
                    (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','monday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                    (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Tuesday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                    (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Wednesday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                    (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Thursday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                    (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Friday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                    (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Saturday','00:00:00','00:00:00'),
                    (NULL,'$res_name','$mail','Sunday','00:00:00','00:00:00')";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

[image]

Comment: i'v realize my error.it's db column data type error.thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO example
  (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

this works for me. Tell me what errors it gives you if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO person(
`id` ,
`name` ,
`email` ,
`phone`
)
VALUES 
( 100,  'John Smith',  'email1@example.com',  '09723282639' ) , 
( 101,  'Jane Doe',  'email2@example.com',  '25655555' )
```

Comment: column names do not match example, also there is no description why your answer is the correct one.